# rsyslogd taking up all my drive space, only when the service is started

Tags: rsyslog

I have configured rsyslogd to write log files to an external drive.  When the service is not started, but the drive is mounted, my disk utilization (by `df`) is low.  As soon as I start rsyslogd, the disk utilization creeps up over a minute or so to very high utilization on the main drive (not the drive that it's logging to.)  Using `du` to try to find a cache file or something else that might be used by rsyslogd shows nothing.  What could be causing this?

Comment: If you run `sudo lsof rsyslogd`, does it have files open for writing on the main drive?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick - libraries and the binary, /dev/log, the and /var/log/syslog on the local drive (which is less than 10 meg).  This is strange.